# How do I make my textview support telugu font?

Tags: java, android

I fetched some data from JSON and added it into my Listview. It's fetching properly. But, in my listview some characters are not supported there? I'm using below code to decode from JSON.

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
```

I'm getting the fonts but with wrong pronunciation as below. How do I correct this?
[image: Example]

Comment: do let me if you find a solution for this, I'm facing the same issue.