# How to convert the content of a UTF-8 file to ASCII to display in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-emulator

Hi. I am writing a sample application to display Telugu fonts in Android. I'm able to read files and display the content in android. But the problem is I am getting the wrong pronunciations in Telugu.

Can any one help me to compare the Telugu characters for encoding and correct the wrong pronunciations. Please find the code below.

Appreciate your help.

```
public class TeluguTestAppActivity extends Activity {
    float textsize = 12;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        /*Incorporate font file to convert into Telugu fonts */
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), 
                      "fonts/DroidSansRegionalAAD.ttf");

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myFont);
        tv.setTypeface(tf);
        String st = readText();
        tv.setText(st);        
    }

    private String readText(){
        StringBuffer sb = null;
        BufferedReader bufReader = null;
            /* Reading txt file which is placed in raw folder. 
            This contains telugu information. */
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ad1);
        try {
            bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                           inputStream, "UTF-8"));

        sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;

            while((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }        
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with UTF-8>?

Comment: Text Files are fine. Only the problem is, wrong pronunciations while displaying in android device since the data is belongs to international language.

Comment: Oh ok not verbally. You need it to be UNIcode for international language.

Comment: My data file contain below characters
1 ఆదియందు దేవుడు భూమ్యాకాశములను సృజించెను.
any idea how to do unicode with this

Comment: Yup, do you have to encode it as UTF-8 for any reason in the first placE?

Comment: B'coz I created txt files in UTF-8 format. I like to follow any suggestions to complete this. I want to complete Bible in my own language.

Comment: It has most likely been done already if you wanna save some time. However, you cant ever have your text in UTF-8 or you can lose data that UTF-8 doesn't support.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an issue: `bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( 
                                           inputStream, "UTF-8"));`
ASCII doesn't have support for international languages, so, you are losing your data from the file that specified the "pronounciation". Try not specifying an encoding or use UTF-16.

EDIT: For your specified language it doesn't.
EDIT: Yup I confused UTF-8 with ASCII. Still doesn't work though. Because the question says he wants to convert to ASCII.

Comment: I tried UTF-16 also by creating different file. Still same issue. There is no change. Since I don't have enough reputations, not able to post the screen shot. 

bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-16"));

Comment: If you take the sting ("ఆదియందు దేవుడు భూమ్యాకాశములను సృజించెను"), result should be as it is in mobile device also.

Comment: Yes, I have two sets of files. UTF-16 and UTF-8

Comment: My issues is similar to below issue.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207431/how-do-i-make-my-textview-support-telugu-font

Comment: UTF-8 supports all the Unicode characters (See the very first sentence in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). And not specifying an encoding doesn't help: it would use the platform's default encoding (which could very well be UTF-8). Use the encoding used to encode the file.

Comment: I am really looking for how to do the encoding for my Language characters. any example by any chance?